# How do I create and delete (or move) a freeform shape in Microsoft Visual Basic Express 2010

Tags: vb.net, excel, basic, vba

I have managed to create and delete multiple freeform shapes in Microsoft Excel through a set of VBA commands and would like to do the same with Microsoft Visual Basic Express 2010 but really am getting nowhere! The creation code in Excel looks something like:

```
With Sheet1.Shapes.BuildFreeform(msoEditingAuto, triXArray(1), triYArray(1))
    For cnt = 2 To 4
        .AddNodes msoSegmentLine, msoEditingAuto, triXArray(cnt), triYArray(cnt)
    Next
End With
```

triXArray() and triYArray() are arrays of the X and Y coordinates of the points and cnt is the counter which loops through the items (it's a triangle).

Comment: This doesn't tell me how to create it in Visual Basic Express though, else I have have worked that out, honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you create and delete a freeform shape in Excel from VB.Net

You need to assign the freeform to a shape after you `.ConvertToShape()`. That ways, you can work (delete, move) with it

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports MsoEd = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEditingType
Imports MsoSg = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoSegmentType

Public Class Form1
    '~~> Define your Excel Objects
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim shpFF As Excel.FreeformBuilder
    Dim Shp As Excel.Shape

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        '~~> Add a New Workbook
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
        '~~> Work with first sheet
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets(1)

        '~~> Create the Freeform shape
        shpFF = xlWorkSheet.Shapes.BuildFreeform(MsoEd.msoEditingCorner, 360, 200)

        With shpFF
            '~~> Add the nodes. You can use your array method as well
            .AddNodes(MsoSg.msoSegmentCurve, MsoEd.msoEditingCorner, _
             380, 230, 400, 250, 450, 300)
            .AddNodes(MsoSg.msoSegmentCurve, MsoEd.msoEditingAuto, 480, 200)
            .AddNodes(MsoSg.msoSegmentLine, MsoEd.msoEditingAuto, 480, 400)
            .AddNodes(MsoSg.msoSegmentLine, MsoEd.msoEditingAuto, 360, 200)

            '~~> Convert it to shape and assign it
            Shp = .ConvertToShape()

            '~~> Display Excel
            xlApp.Visible = True
        End With

        MessageBox.Show ("Wait")

        '~~> Delete the shape
        Shp.Delete()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Ah, right - thanks! Misunderstanding on my side there.

Comment: So is your query sorted?

Comment: I've been piping it through and having no luck. I'm using Visual Basic Express 2010, which might simply be the wrong app.

Comment: Quite a few, but ones along the lines of **'MsoEd' is not declared**, which it is, or **'MsoEditingAuto' is not declared**. I did start with the 3 imports...

Comment: Did you add a reference to Excel Object Library?

Comment: As far as your question is concerned, I have already answered that. Rest I recommend learning more about Excel Automation from VB.Net [Here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/vb-dot-net-and-excel/) :)